# Nexus Mod Manager and Archive Files

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods, nexus-mod-manager

The Nexus Mod Manager has my non-steam mod archives stored in C:\Games\Skyrim\mods. Do the archives I have downloaded contain redundant information, and do I need to keep these downloaded copies? Will the archives sorted by NMM be sufficient for the future?

Comment: I think you need to describe the situation better. It seems there are two separate sets of archives, one in NMM mod folder, and another downloaded somehow that is somewhere else? And you think they contain redundant information?

Comment: @Deltharis Yes, that explains it in a much nicer way! I'll change my original post to reflect this, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer to this question:

No, you do not need to keep the mod archive files that you have downloaded. NMM seems to make a copy of these archives in the directory you setup for each game. The archives you download from the Nexus or other sites can safely be deleted.